# setting the view matrix

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am trying to convert my C# XNA project to WebGL using Three.js.

So far its going very well, but I am currently working on my camera. With XNA you can easily send the view matrix to the shader.

I'm sure I'm just not seeing what I am supposed to be seeing in the documentation.

My CameraManager class has a MouseMoved event handler.

```
CameraManager.prototype.MouseMoved = function( changeVector ) {    
    var q1 = new THREE.Quaternion();
    q1.setFromAxisAngle(this.left, (( Math.PI / 4 ) / 200) * changeVector.y);
    var q2 = new THREE.Quaternion();
    q2.setFromAxisAngle(this.left, (( -Math.PI / 4 ) / 200) * changeVector.x);
    var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    q.multiply(q1, q2);

    q.multiplyVector3(this.direction);
    q.multiplyVector3(this.left);
}
```

The CameraManager also has an update method that updates the View matrix.

```
CameraManager.prototype.CreateLookAt = function() {
    var target = this.position.clone();
    target.addSelf(this.direction);
    this.view = THREE.Matrix4.CreateLookAt(this.position, target, this.up);    
}

THREE.Matrix4.CreateLookAt = function(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, upVector) {
    var zAxis = new THREE.Vector3();
    zAxis.sub(cameraPosition, cameraTarget);    
    zAxis.normalize();

    var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3();
    xAxis.cross(upVector, zAxis);
    xAxis.normalize();

    var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3();
    yAxis.cross(zAxis, xAxis);

    return new THREE.Matrix4(
         xAxis.x,           yAxis.x,           zAxis.x,          0,
         xAxis.y,           yAxis.y,           zAxis.y,          0,
         xAxis.z,           yAxis.z,           zAxis.z,          0,
        -xAxis.dot(cameraPosition),  -yAxis.dot(cameraPosition),  -zAxis.dot(cameraPosition),  l
    ); 
}
```

Just wondering how I can set the view matrix for the camera.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just set your matrix properties by apart like so:

```
var m = getYourNewMatrix();
camera.position = m.decompose()[ 0 ];
camera.rotation = m.decompose()[ 1 ];
camera.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: Hey,

So I tried your suggestion. However, I am looking at the result of m.decompose and none of the arrays of values returned have the correct position. It seems like the view matrix does have them but actually getting the values from the elements array from the THREE.Matrix4 didn't work either...

Comment: have you checked on the values that you are getting originally from your "new matrix"? May be something with your calculations? Because if you set right values to `camera.position`, then you'll get your position set right))

Comment: So, I decided to end up just setting camera.position to something simple. I can now see my mesh being drawn! Looks like I'll need to find a tutorial on how to create a first person camera.

Comment: Best wishes! Anyway I think that it is much more efficient changing separate values like `camera.position` and `camera.lookAt()` instead of changing the whole matrix, that's going to have just few of its 16 values changed at any certain moment of rendering.